# Content rules does not work for my new content type

Tags: plone, contentrules

I created a content type based on ATDocument. I setup a rule when my content type is added to a folder, an email is sent. But this does not work. The rule works fine for any other standard content type (document, file,etc.).
What do i miss. What should i look at ?

My Plone version is 4.2.0.1

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Do other, simple rules work with your content type? e.g. a rule to add a log entry when the object is modified.

Comment: It works fine when i modify the object in its container. I can get an email or a notification then.  But when i add an object, it does not.

Comment: If you look in `plone.app.contentrules.handlers.added` you'll see that "there is special handling for Archetypes objects". You might try setting an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` breakpoint in there, restarting, adding your object and checking that the code executed proceeds as you expect.